# Prefetch Related not working as expected

Tags: django, django-models, django-related-manager

I'm developing an API with Django 1.11.11 and python 3.6.4. I have the following model:

```
class Subsection(models.Model):
    genres = models.ManyToManyField(Genre, blank=True, default=None)
    tags = models.ManyToManyField(Tag, blank=True, default=None)
```

And I'm doing the following query:

```
subsection = Subsection.objects.filter(**q_objects).prefetch_related('genres', 'tags').first()
```

So, then I can do:

```
genres = subsection.genres.all()
tags = subsection.tags.all()
```

However, this is doing new calls even the prefetch_related, what am I doing wrong?

Thanks in advance

Comment: How have you found this is running additional queries?  To me this seems correct.  Try to print(subsection._prefetched_objects_cache),  it shouldn't be empty

Comment: I'm checking this on my tests with assuredNumQueries

Comment: Can you please provide the test and the code under the test if any? If you are testing View,  maybe I know the issue

Comment: The test is just a call to the view that does the code written above:     def test_numQueries(self):
        with self.assertNumQueries(3):
            self.client.get(url)

Comment: The strange thing here is even if prefetch related doesn't work,  that two queries are not used and due to lazy evaluation cannot call the DB..

Comment: Don't use the browsable API, it'll make extra query on its own to fill the dropdown for example.

Comment: Thanks for your help. Those two queries are used in order to serialize the data, thats why the query is done; however, I don't understand why the queries are being done even the prefetch_related. Thanks a lot!

Comment: If you are using UpdateModelMixin,  then take a look at it source code and you will see the reason for additional queries